# Unable to verify meta description by Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I changed xml path like below. But it gives invalid xml path type of error:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyAttribute</td>
    <td>//meta[@name='description'] and @content</td>
    <td>'Rent Vacation Rentals direc'</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working by this code:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//meta[@name='description' and @content='Content']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** the following solution:

```
<tr>
<td>verifyAttribute</td>
<td>//meta[@name='description']@content</td>
<td>'Rent Vacation Rentals more than 250,000 vacation properties.'</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why? And the original poster has the AND within the [ ], think your "instead of" is wrong :)

Comment: You're right, thanks. I've corrected the answer.